# Average remaining lifetime for him and her

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, actuarial-science

She (40) is chosen from the population with maximum age 121. Average remaining lifetime at age $x$ is equal $\frac{121-x}{2.4}$ for $x<121$.

He (30) is chosen from the population with maximum age 98. Average remaining lifetime at age $x$ is equal $\frac{98-x}{2.7}$ for $x<98$.

His and her lifespans are independent. 
Calculate the probability that both of them will live longer than 37 years.

So I have to calculate $_{37}p_{40} \cdot _{37}p_{30}$ but I do not know how to take these probabilities from the average lifetime.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If she is already $40$ years old, then she is guaranteed to live longer than $37$ years, so you just have to compute the probability that he lives longer than $37$ years.

Comment: @N.F. Taussig. I was thinking that this may be another $37$ years with ages $77$ and $67$. It says remaining lifetime in the title.

Comment: Yes, I have to compute that she will live longer than 77 and he will live longer than 67.

Comment: You can't get the probabilities just from the average. You need to know more about the distribution. How are the ages distributed? What is the variance? For example, if the variance were zero these probabilities would be one.